# Build pagination manually for external API Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, http

I'm consuming an external API, and I would like to create some sort of pagination for the index action. The API returns 15 elements (which is the limit I specified in the HttParty query hash) and I can add the "page" option too. For starters, I tried putting an incremental in the view and passing it as a param, and it works but only for one page (ex. from page 1 to 2) and then it just reloads the second page. How could I achieve my goal? I know there are some gems out there but I would like to learn it myself. Here's the code:

controller

```rb
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  BASE_URL='https://api.stagingeb.com/v1/properties'
  HEADERS = { 
    "X-Authorization"  => ENV['API_KEY']
  }

  def index
    page = params[:page]
    query = {
      "limit" => "15",
      "page" => page || 1
    }
    request = HTTParty.get(BASE_URL, :query => query, :headers => HEADERS)
    @response = JSON.parse(request.body)
  end

  def show
    request = HTTParty.get(BASE_URL + "/#{params[:id]}", :headers => HEADERS)
    @response = JSON.parse(request.body)
  end
  
end
```

view

```html
<h1 class="index-heading">Listing all properties</h1>
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <%@response["content"].each do |property|%>
    <div class="property-card">
      <div class="image">
        <%if property["title_image_thumb"]%>
          <%=image_tag property["title_image_thumb"]%>
        <%else%>
          <p class="noimage"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> No image</p>
        <%end%>
      </div>
      <div class="card-text">
        <p class="public-id"><%=property["public_id"]%></p>
        <p class="title"><%=property["title"]%></p>
        <p class="type"><%=property["property_type"]%></p>
        <p class="type"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> <%=property["location"]%></p>
      </div>
      <div class="property-link">
        <%=link_to 'Go to property', "properties/#{property["public_id"]}"%>
      </div>
    </div>
  <%end%>
</div>
<div class="pagination">
  <%i = 1%>
  <%=link_to 'Next page', root_path(:page => i+=1)>
</div>
```

PD: My goal is to add two buttons, one for the previous page and one for the next page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the page you are currently showing when rendering the view:

```
<div class="pagination">
  <%=link_to 'Next page', root_path(:page => @current_page + 1)>
</div>
```

To achieve this you need to set in the controller:

```rb
  def index
    @current_page = [1, params[:page].to_i].max
    query = {
      "limit" => "15",
      "page" => @current_page
    }
    request = HTTParty.get(BASE_URL, :query => query, :headers => HEADERS)
    @response = JSON.parse(request.body)
  end
```